# converting units (ft to cm) entered as factors to integers in R

Tags: r, units-of-measurement

I'm trying write a function in R that converts heights entered in different units into centimeters.

In the dataframe, heights are either entered in centimeters (e.g. 175), meters, (e.g. 1.83), or feet and inches (e.g. 5ft4, or even 5ft9.5).
What I need to do is convert factors containing characters ("ft" or ".") into integers, but I have no idea how to approach this practically.

Any help would be more than welcome :)

Comment: what have you done so far, where is the problem?

Comment: `gsub('ft|[.]','',c('5ft4','5ft9.5'))`

Comment: so I'm at a very basic level of R, and can't even seem to convert the factors of the dataframe into integers.

I was trying to make a for-if loop and use the grepl function to return elements containing ft, but since they're not even integers I have no idea how to convert them into a state where I could use a conversion factor.

Comment: get a book with first steps in R and start doing so. Then you will learn. Probably you have a challenge too big for now. The way is also not very clear to you, it seems

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(stringr)

  df <- tibble(measurementType = c("feet", "cm", "m"), height = c("5ft8.5", 175, 1.83))

  df %>% mutate(height = ifelse(measurementType == "feet",
                                 as.numeric(unlist(str_split(height, "ft"))[1]) * 12 + as.numeric(unlist(str_split(height, "ft"))[2]), 
                                as.numeric(height))) %>% 
       mutate(heightInCm = case_when(measurementType == "feet" ~ height * 2.54,
                                     measurementType == "m" ~ height * 100,
                                     TRUE ~ height))
```